# Are alcoholic beverages more expensive at night in Japan (in bars)?

Tags: japan, alcohol, taxes

I just went to a bar in Tokyo and asked for two beers (¥700 each). When we asked for the bill, the waitress charged us ¥2400. When I pointed out the error, she said something about taxes in Japan.

Is this true? Are alcoholic beverages more expensive in Japan from a certain hour?

Comment: Incidentally, I have seen something like that in Paris too. Bars with extra charges for drinks consumed upstairs, at the terrace, or after 18:00 (and thus possibly two distinct extra charges if you drink upstairs after 6?).

Comment: In this case it was specifically weird as it was not a touristic area and we were the only clients. It was itemized in the hand-written receipt, that is true.

Comment: @HectorLorenzo: If you have a receipt and really want to know what it was about, you could post a picture of it for people to decipher.

Comment: It's not unusual to have extra charges for late night service in some places (all over the world). What time was it? Though of course those would be charges, not taxes.

Comment: @Relaxed: Extra charges for terraces (or table far from the counter) are common in France. Extra charge after 6PM is not common (maybe a Paris thing?); more common would be a discount before 6PM.

Comment: How did you make the logical leap from "something about taxes" to "are alcoholic beverages more expensive at night"?

Comment: @Amani Kilumanga It was just a hypothesis, given the high taxation on alcohol in Japan.

Comment: @Taladris Which parts of France are you familiar with? Extra charges for terraces are not common either.

Comment: Did they give you a small dish with your drinks ?

Comment: You may want to specify "in bars" in the title. In other places such as convenience stores, they definitely are not. (By the way, I never frequent bars and now I know why. 700 for a beer?)

Comment: @Relaxed: I lived mostly in an "extended Burgundy" that ranges from Lyon to Paris (not including Paris) and Orleans to Bezancon. I also spend a lot of time in a "great South area" from Grenoble to Toulouse. I agree that an extra charge for a terrace in the South of France would be a deterrent for many local customers; but, without being very common, it is common enough in Burgundy.

Comment: If you don't mind it could you tell me the name of the bar? Maybe they write it in website if they have a cover charge.

Comment: I can't even find it on Google Maps. I'll write it down tomorrow and give it to you.

Comment: @fkraiem You're right, I've edited the title for it to be more accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**No**, it's not true - but perhaps you misunderstood? Bars in Japan very commonly have a cover charge, typically in the 500-1000 yen range (per person), that could well explain the difference.

Comment: Isn't cover charge restricted to sexy bars?

Comment: @Taladris not in Japan.